# How do I optimize celery workers automatically without using a yml file while building the image

Tags: apache-superset

**I am trying to run the celery workers automatically without building the image from a docker-compose.yml file. The reason being I want a production ready image.**

Here is my superset_config.py code:

```
    BROKER_URL = 'redis://%s:%s/0' % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)

    CELERY_IMPORTS = ('superset.sql_lab', "superset.tasks", "superset.tasks.thumbnails", )

    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://%s:%s/0' % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)

    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1

    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = False

    CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {

        'sql_lab.get_sql_results': {

            'rate_limit': '100/s',

        },

        'email_reports.send': {

            'rate_limit': '1/s',

            'time_limit': 120,

            'soft_time_limit': 150,

            'ignore_result': True,

        },

    }

    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'reports.scheduler': {

            'task': 'reports.scheduler',

            'schedule': crontab(minute='*', hour='*'),

        },

        'reports.prune_log': {

            'task': 'reports.prune_log',

            'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),

        },

        'cache-warmup-hourly': {

            'task': 'cache-warmup',

            'schedule': crontab(minute='*/30', hour='*'),

            'kwargs': {

                'strategy_name': 'top_n_dashboards',

                'top_n': 10,

                'since': '7 days ago',

            },

    },

    }

    CELERY_TASK_PROTOCOL = 1

CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

SCREENSHOT_LOCATE_WAIT = 100

SCREENSHOT_LOAD_WAIT = 600

EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS = True
```

I however have to bash to the container and manually run the following commands to optimize the configuration set:

```
*celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app beat*
*celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker --pool=prefork -O fair -c 4*
```

I want to automate this process while utilizing production ready docker image.
Please help.